# Selecting an element at from a number XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I got an XML that Looks like this

```
<TripList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlopen.rejseplanen.dk/xml/rest/hafasRestTrip.xsd">
   <Trip>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 61" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 52" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
   </Trip>
   <Trip>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 61" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 52" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
   </Trip>
   <Trip>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 191" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 152" type="BUS">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
   </Trip>
   <Trip>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="Bus 31" type="TB">...</Leg>
      <Leg name="til fods" type="WALK">...</Leg>
   </Trip>
</TripList>
```

I need to select the the "Third" Trip Element using XDocument in Windows Phone, How would I go about that?

I've tried stuff like

```
foreach (var Stykke in xdoc.Root.Elements("Trip")[2].Elements("Leg"))
{
}
```

As you can see, Would like to get all the Leg elements from the third.

This may be a very stupid question, but I was unable to find appropriate answer to my question anywhere else.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP7 , but can you use XPath ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ElementAt` could work for you.

What you're looking for is

```
foreach (var Stykke in xdoc.Root.Elements("Trip").ElementAt(2).Elements("Leg"))
{
}
```

or if you wanted to you could also use `ToList` and then get the result using the indexer.:

```
foreach (var Stykke in xdoc.Root.Elements("Trip").ToList()[2].Elements("Leg"))
{
}
```

I'm not sure if WP7 lets you use those methods. If it doesn't, please comment and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
xdoc.Descendants("Trip")[2].Descendants("Leg")
```

Comment: Don't see how this is any different... Descendants also returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, and `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have an indexer...

Comment: I would add that if XmlDocument class is an option, I find it much more satisfying to use when I need to traverse an XML document discretely.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML you ll have your query like

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load(Path);
var ThirdTripElement = X.Element("TripList")
      .Elements("Trip")
      .ElementAt(2)
      .Elements("Leg")
      .Select(E => new { Name = E.Attribute("name").Value, 
                         Type = E.Attribute("type").Value });
```

Comment: How do you know what he wants to `Select`? Otherwise quite a good answer.

Comment: OP can change the select items. I think the issue was with reading the XML tags.

Comment: The issue was with getting the element at an index.